# Get index value from dropdown form

Tags: php, jquery, html

I have a dropdown that is filled by a database and everything works well. However I want to pass a parameter to php based on the value of the dropdown which I can do. If I force the var to have a particular number it gets the corresponding item in the database. I'm having a problem to get the value of a dropdown. I've tried all the suggestions here in the forum and nothing works in this particular area of my code. I have it working on another piece of my code but not on this particular one and I don't know why. Here is my code:

```
<select id="servicos"  onChange="return selectServ();">
    <option value="item" class="itemoption">Serviço</option>
```

This is the code that is not working:

```
function selectServ() {
    var e = document.getElementById("servicos");
    var idserv = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    $.getJSON("http://ib.esy.es/gestao/_php/servicos_threadingpreco.php", { serv: idserv }, null).then(function(data) {
        console.log(data);
        var tr = data
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var tr = $('<tr/>');

            // Indexing into data.report for each td element
            $(tr).append("<td>" + data[i].preco + "</td>");
            $('.table1').append(tr);
        }
    });
}
```

If I put

```
var idserv = "1"
```

It is working, however this:

```
var e = document.getElementById("servicos");
var idserv = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

Is not getting a value. The console log gives:

> selectdynamicpreco.html:76 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).value is not a function

Comment: Why are you using javascript if you have jQuery included? Thats like using a spoon instead of a spade. For instance: why not use `$('servicos').val();`

Comment: Same error on the console log.

Comment: @Peter I'm sorry your comment is working, I was just uploading the incorrect file. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using jQuery to get the value of the dropdown:
$('#dropdown').val() will give you the selected value of the drop down element. Use this to get the selected options text.

`$("#dropdown option:selected").text();`

Should get you the text value of the dropdown.

Comment: Sorry meant $("#dropdown option:selected").text();

Comment: Are you including jQuery?

Comment: Also try printing the contents of idserv to see what it is your trying to pass through. Try with console.log(idserv);

Comment: @Ross Yes I'm including it, The rest of my code is working which includes an area where I use the same code.

Comment: What is the error you're getting now with above code after commenting out the line with e.options[e.selectedIndex].value

Comment: @Ross I'm getting an error of Error type on "value"

Comment: Have you removed the line with e.options[e.selectedIndex].value in it?

Comment: So you'not getting 'TypeError: $(...).value is not a function' anymore>

Answer (score 0):

This is working on another piece of the code

```
<script>
function selectCat(){
$('#servicos').change(function() {
  $('#demo').text($(this).find(":selected").text());
});
//for textbox use $('#txtEntry2').val($(this).find(":selected").text());
    var e = document.getElementById("categoria");
    var servSelected = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    var url = "";

  var items="";
  if(servSelected === "1"){
  url = "http://ib.esy.es/gestao/_php/servicos_threading.php";
  }
  if(servSelected === "2"){
  url = "http://ib.esy.es/gestao/_php/servicos_sobrancelhas.php";
  }
  if(servSelected === "3"){
  url = "http://ib.esy.es/gestao/_php/servicos_manicure.php";
  }
  $.getJSON(url,function(data){

    $.each(data,function(index,item) 
    {
      items+="<option value='"+item.ID+"'>"+item.servico+"</option>";
    });
    $("#servicos").html(items); 
  });
};
</script>
```